# Увеличивается количество открываемых активити, finish() не закрывает все

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня проблема:

```
btLogin.setOnClickListener  {
            try {
                if (etLogin.text.toString() != "" || etPassword.text.toString() != ""){
                    val repository = Repository()
                    val viewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(repository)
                    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
                    viewModel.getLogin()
                    viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            etLogin.text.clear()
                            etPassword.text.clear()
                            val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        } else {
                            val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Неправильный логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            myToast.show()
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{
                    val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Не введен логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    myToast.show()
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Exeption: \n ${e.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                myToast.show()
            }
        }
```

Первый раз активити `MainMenuActivity` открывается один раз, и по нажатию кнопки "назад" возвращаюсь обратно. Но с каждым последующим разом количество открытых активити увеличивается на один.

Как исправить, чтобы `MainMenuActivity` открывалось один раз, или по нажатию на `MainMenuActivity` кнопки назад активити закрывалась с первого раза?

Comment: Простого решения тут нет. Мерзкий гугл предлагает использовать для этого  `SingleLiveEvent` - https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Comment: возможно поможет https://medium.com/swlh/truly-understand-tasks-and-back-stack-intent-flags-of-activity-2a137c401eca

Comment: А что `Observer` удалять после того как отработал?

Comment: не подскажете как?

Answer (score 0):

удалил Observer и все заработало

```
viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            etLogin.text.clear()
                            etPassword.text.clear()
                            viewModel.myResponse.removeObservers(this)
                            val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
```